# Plot several densities on one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a data frame with a MultiIndex (expenditure, groupid):

```
                        coef    stderr    N
expenditure groupid                         
TOTEXPCQ    176      3745.124  858.1998   81
            358     -1926.703  1036.636   75
            109      239.3678   639.373  280
            769      6406.512  1823.979   96
            775      2364.655  1392.187  220
```

I can get the density using `df['coef'].plot(kind='density')`. I would like to group these densities by the outer level of the MultiIndex (expenditure), and draw the different densities for different levels of expenditure into the same plot.

How would I achieve this? Bonus: label the different expenditure graphs with the 'expenditure' value

**Answer**

My initial approach was to merge the different kdes by generating one `ax` object and passing that along, but the accepted answer inspired me to rather generate one df with the group identifiers as columns:

```
n = 25
df = pd.DataFrame({'expenditure' : np.random.choice(['foo','bar'], n),
                   'groupid' : np.random.choice(['one','two'], n),
                  'coef' : np.random.randn(n)})
df2 = df[['expenditure', 'coef']].pivot_table(index=df.index, columns='expenditure', values='coef')
df2.plot(kind='kde')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that ended up being much harder than I expected. Seemed easy in concept, but (yet again) concept and practice really differed.

Set up some toy data:

```
n = 25
df = pd.DataFrame({'expenditure' : np.random.choice(['foo','bar'], n),
                   'groupid' : np.random.choice(['one','two'], n),
                  'coef' : randn(n)})
```

Then group by `expenditure`, iterate through each expenditure, pivot the data, and plot the kde:

```
gExp = df.groupby('expenditure')
for exp in gExp:
    print exp[0]
    gGroupid = exp[1].groupby('groupid')
    g = exp[1][['groupid','coef']].reset_index(drop=True)
    gpt = g.pivot_table(index = g.index, columns='groupid', values='coef')
    gpt.plot(kind='kde').set_title(exp[0])
    show()
```

Results in:

[image]
[image]

It took some trial and error to figure out the data had to be pivoted before plotting.

Comment: This forced me to finally understand when to use pivot_table() instead of pivot()